# How to append <i> inside of <a> tag from jquery?

Tags: html, jquery

How can I append the icon tag inside of `<a>` tag? I tried with this but it does not appear in the page.

```
<li class="nav-item">
   <a class="interested-link nav-link" href="{{ url('user/interested_properties') }}" id="intrst_prop_count">
     <i class="fa fa-star"></i>
   </a>
</li>
```

To `<a>` tag from I set text like this and tried to send the `<i>` like this,

```
success: function (result) {
   if (result.count != null)
       $('#intrst_prop_count').append('<i class="fa fa-star"></i>')
       $('#intrst_prop_count').text('Interested (' + result.count + ')');
       $('#interested').attr('value', true);
   },
```

What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: a tag as in anchor tag? there is no href="" there

Comment: The call to `$('#intrst_prop_count').text('Inter....` overwrites the appended content

Comment: @ProfessorAbronsius right, what's the solution then ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you set an element's `.text()`, you overwrite its existing contents. Use `.append()`:

```js
$("button").click(function() {
  $('#intrst_prop_count')
    .append('<span class="fa fa-star"></span>')
    .append('Interested (' + 30 + ')')
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/5.15.3/css/all.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />

<ul>
  <li class="nav-item">
    <a class="interested-link nav-link" href="{{ url('user/interested_properties') }}" id="intrst_prop_count">
    </a>
  </li>
</ul>

<button>Do it</button>
```

Comment: and the method set the value, is invoke after some button click event then more than one texts are rendered on the page, that's why i used the `.text`

Comment: @pl-jay I don't think it's important what happens in other places on the page. :)

Comment: if i append the value to `#intrst_prop_count` and after button click event which set the value to `result.count`, it renders one element per each click event

Comment: even your answer does the same, i just want is only to change the value inside

Comment: @pl-jay That wasn't your question above. But yeah, you could set the element to `.empty()` before.

Comment: ...or you make an separate `<span>` just for the `"Interested: ..."`, and then set the `.text()` of that.

Answer (score 1):

You can set the text and prepend the icon. Setting text will clear any existing content and prepend will add the icon before the text.

Example

```
$('#intrst_prop_count')
 .text('Interested (' + 30 + ')')
 .prepend('<span class="fa fa-star"></span>')
```

```js
$('#intrst_prop_count')
 .text('Interested (' + 30 + ')')
 .prepend('<span class="fa fa-star"></span>')
```

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.0/jquery.min.js"></script>


<li class="nav-item">
   <a class="interested-link nav-link" href="{{ url('user/interested_properties') }}" id="intrst_prop_count">
     <i class="fa fa-star"></i>
   </a>
</li>
```